# Encountered Vagrant Up error on MacOs Big Sur Upgrade

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, macos-big-sur

I just upgraded my mac OS from Catalina to Big Sur. My vagrant used to be working normally before and then I encountered this issue. (Vagrant version: 2.2.13)

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

When I tried to start it manually on the VirtualBox this is the return message:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This question seems to be about general use of Vagrant, which makes it on-topic on Superuser, not here.

Comment: You just need to reinstall a driver. This is a better post for Superuser. In fact it's already been answered over there. Reinstall the Mac equivalent of the virtualbox-dkms package and reboot. https://superuser.com/questions/1285964/how-to-fix-and-prevent-virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating to Big Sur. I downloaded the latest versions of Vagrant, Virtualbox and VirtualBox Extension Pack. Actually, I don't know if installing the Extension Pack was necessary.

And in the system preferences of MacOS, in Privacy and Security, I had to approve the update from Oracle.

After these steps, I was able to 'vagrant up' again.

Comment: Approving the update seems to be the solution for this problem, after Virtualbox was updated. Thank you so much! :) This should be the accepted answer as it is the most comprehensive one.

Comment: Approving the update is a solution for sure.

Comment: upgrade the Virtual BOX and Vagrant both but still not working

Comment: I ignored the privacy setting and did not double-check, thanks all, the problem is solved!

Comment: Hello from Big Sur - I can confirm that you have to upgrade 3 things - Vagrant itself, VirtualBox and VB Extension Pack. It is also mandatory to restart macOS after granting permission via Security & Privacy. Once this is done, everything should be back to normal.

Comment: Yes, to install the extension pack was fundamental for me, just after that I got the  message to approve the update from Oracle.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem without downloading Extension Pack.
I downloaded the .dmg file of the current version of my VirtualBox from the official site. Then run the official installer script that appears along with the .pkg when the .dmg is opened. Then proceeded to download, install and approve according to your instructions.  latest VirtualBox 6.1.x

Comment: Big Sur, system pref -> security & privacy -> general -> unlock to make changes -> advanced -> approve and reboot

Comment: restarting your computer after doing the above steps fixed it for me.

Answer (score 12):

Updating VirtualBox to 6.1.16 did it for me.
I did not update Vagrant

Comment: I also did the same thing. Downloaded the latest 6.1 version and installed it. Granted permission and did a reboot. Boom!! Didn't do anything to vagrant. Working fine. +1

Answer (score 3):

Updating VirtualBox to 6.1.16 did it for me, not working with 6.0.24.
Also reinstalled Vagrant but not sure if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The allow oracle button in privacy and security never showed up in my settings.
Eventually I got it working by booting in recovery mode and running the command

```
csrutil clear
```

After that I was able to allow oracle in security and privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reinstalling both Vagrant and VirtualBox :)

Comment: I tried reinstalling, but I still get the same error. Did you do anything else to make it work?

Comment: I got the installer error when reinstalling VirtualBox as well. After several attempts it suddenly worked. No idea why.

Comment: Installing works fine for me, however I keep getting the same problem as OP (Vagrant 2.2.13; VirtualBox 6.1.16)

Comment: I ignored the privacy setting and did not double check, thanks all, the problem is solved !

Comment: I have Virtualbox Version 6.1.16, and Vagrant 2.2.14 and does not work :/.

Answer (score 0):

I Also just ran into this issue today after updating to Big Sur. Using homebrew to update VirtualBox (v. 6.1.16) and approving in Security & Privacy did not resolve the problem. I had to give VirtualBox Full Disk Access in the `Privacy` Tab of Security & Privacy to solve this.

The last comment form the virtualbox forum is what helped me with the last step.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=98763#p488757

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading virtual box to latest version (6.1.16 at this moment) works for me. Didn't had to upgrade vagrant version.

`vagrant up` worked right after upgrading the virtual box.