# Big Sur MacOS Vagrant issue

Tags: vagrant, apache2

I just updated MacOS to New version (Big Sur). When I tried vagrant up to start the vagrant, it shows error as the following below:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? I've tried install vagrant again already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encountered Vagrant Up error on MacOs Big Sur Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816944/encountered-vagrant-up-error-on-macos-big-sur-upgrade)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved this problem by below steps:

1. Update your virtualbox
2. Update your vagrant
3. Go to `System Preference` then `privacy& security` and Allow the permission in general tap.

Comment: this is the solution.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try Vagrant plugins update with `vagrant plugin update` (see what I did there?) afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too & upgrading my virtualbox to 6.1 solve the issue. Check the thread [here](http://%5Bhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816944/encountered-vagrant-up-error-on-macos-big-sur-upgrade%5D).

But when I tried using virtual v6.0 the error still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I had been updated the VirtualBox even reinstall but the issue did not resolve . After I uninstall and reinstall the Virtualbox, allow permission, and restart my pc then the issue fix. I had followed the bellow steps:

1. Uninstall VirtualBox via their official uninstaller script
2. Do a clean install of VirtualBox using VirtualBox.pkg
3. Adjust the privacy settings of Big Sur: System Preferences > Security and Privacy > click the unlock button
4. Restart pc